# Permission denied on entrypoint when trying to update Elastic Beanstalk via GitHub Actions

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, github-actions

I feel this might be an IAM question, but I don't really know where to begin. I have a Docker-based EBS environment that works great when I update it manually. However, when I update it with GitHub Actions, the container fails with the following message.

```
unable to start container process: exec: "./docker/entrypoint.sh": permission denied: unknown.
```

My CD pipeline authenticates, push a new Docker image to the registry, and then updates the `Dockerrun.aws.js` by editing the image name. The workflow runs ok: the image is pushed, and the `Dockerrun.aws.js` is correct... and yet the environment fails to launch.

```yaml
name: Release

on:
  push:
    tags:
    - 'v*'

jobs:
  deploy-to-aws-ebs:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    environment: staging
    permissions:
      id-token: write
      contents: read
    env:
      AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
      AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
    steps:
      - name: Check out the repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Configure AWS credentials
        uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v1
        with:
          role-to-assume: arn:aws:iam::${{ secrets.AWS_ACCOUNT_ID }}:role/ServiceRoleForEBSDeploy
          aws-region: ${{ secrets.AWS_DEFAULT_REGION }}

      - name: Login to Amazon ECR
        id: login-ecr
        uses: aws-actions/amazon-ecr-login@v1

      - name: Get tag name
        run: echo "tag=`echo ${{ github.ref }} | sed -e 's/\./-/g' | cut -c11-`-`echo ${{ github.sha }} | cut -c1-8`" >> $GITHUB_ENV

      - name: Build, tag, and push docker image to Amazon ECR
        env:
          REGISTRY: ${{ steps.login-ecr.outputs.registry }}
          REPOSITORY: docker_repository
          IMAGE_TAG: ${{ env.tag }}
        run: |
          docker build -t $REGISTRY/$REPOSITORY:$IMAGE_TAG .
          docker push $REGISTRY/$REPOSITORY:$IMAGE_TAG
          echo "IMAGE_NAME=$REGISTRY/$REPOSITORY:$IMAGE_TAG" >> $GITHUB_ENV

      - name: Create deployment package
        run: |
          sed -e "s|<IMAGE_NAME>|${{ env.IMAGE_NAME }}|g" \
            docker/Dockerrun.aws.template.json > Dockerrun.aws.json
          cat Dockerrun.aws.json

      - name: Deploy to AWS Elastic Beanstalk
        env:
          AWS_EBS_APP_NAME: app_name
          AWS_EBS_ENV_NAME: env_name
        run: |
          aws s3 cp Dockerrun.aws.json s3://${{ secrets.AWS_S3_BUCKET_NAME }}/versions/${{ env.tag }}-Dockerrun.aws.json
          aws elasticbeanstalk create-application-version \
            --application-name $AWS_EBS_APP_NAME \
            --source-bundle S3Bucket=${{ secrets.AWS_S3_BUCKET_NAME }},S3Key=versions/${{ env.tag }}-Dockerrun.aws.json \
            --version-label ${{ env.tag }}
          aws elasticbeanstalk update-environment \
            --application-name $AWS_EBS_APP_NAME \
            --environment-name $AWS_EBS_ENV_NAME \
            --version-label ${{ env.tag }}
```

Meanwhile, the Dockerfile is your basic Django stuff.

```
FROM python:3.10-slim-buster

ARG APP_HOME=/code \
    USERNAME=user101

WORKDIR ${APP_HOME}

RUN addgroup --system ${USERNAME} \
    && adduser --system --ingroup ${USERNAME} ${USERNAME}

RUN apt-get update --yes --quiet && apt-get install --no-install-recommends --yes --quiet \
    # dependencies for building Python packages
    build-essential \
    # psycopg2 dependencies
    libpq-dev \
    # dev utils
    git \
    # cleanup
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*


COPY . --chown=${USERNAME}:${USERNAME} ${APP_HOME} ${APP_HOME}

RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install poetry
RUN poetry install --no-interaction --no-ansi
EXPOSE 80
USER ${USERNAME}

ENTRYPOINT ["./docker/entrypoint.sh" ]
CMD ["gunicorn", "config.wsgi:application", "--bind", ":80"]
```

My guess is that EBS is trying to build the environment with the GitHub Actions service user? Does that make sense? Should it be using the user defined in the Dockerfile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with IAM permissions.
You just need to make your script executable:

```bash
$ chmod +x ./docker/entrypoint.sh
```

You can also run it inside the Dockerfile before the `ENTRYPOINT` command:

```
RUN chmod +x ./docker/entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["./docker/entrypoint.sh" ]
```

Comment: This worked, thanks! I was under the impression that, because I used the `chown` command, that would be enough.